# Why is some of my website content not loading?

Tags: html, web, resources, assets

Every time I reload my website some of the assets or resources won't load. Sometimes everything loads, sometimes half of it loads. The resources will vary each time on reload. How would I fix this?

- I also tried a new SSL and web.config file and nothing worked

[Website Source Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KnTwl.png)

[Web Dev Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnYTF.png)

[Original Source Files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f7KQp.png)

My current HTML:

```
    <link href="./resources/lib/aos/aos.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="./resources/lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="./resources/lib/bootstrap-icons/bootstrap-icons.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="./resources/lib/boxicons/css/boxicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="./resources/lib/glightbox/css/glightbox.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="./resources/lib/remixicon/remixicon.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="./resources/lib/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

I've also tried:

```
<link href="https://devovation.com/resources/lib/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<link>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-link-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Answer (score 0):

This may be caused by client (browser) caching. Try hot refresh, it may work.

On Windows, `Ctrl shift r`
On Mac, `Command shift r`

You can also Clear your browser cache.

If you are using CDN files (which I don't think so), hot refresh will help.

I hope this helps